# json merge, array push & sort & remove doubles

Tags: javascript, json, merge

```
var d=[
  {
    'fn':'john',
    'en':'doe',
    'k':['0','5','44']
  },

  {
    'en':'bark',
    'k':[,'25','44']
  }
];
```

merge(d[0],d[1]); should return this:

```
  {
    'fn':'john',
    'en':'bark',
    'k':['0','5','25','44']
  }
```

It's a common merge, only difference is that the arrays gets pushed if they are different (just like the **fn** variable, it just gets added, or like the **en** variable, it gets replaced, or like the **k** array, it gets pushed if it's different)(and **sorted** at the same time)

**Edit 1**
Writing the script for me is not what I'm asking for, I'm not familiar with "is array" and "hasPropery" since I am not familiar with that, I'm asking for a help in a direction, and I am using nodejs so jquery is a no-no.

**Edit 2**
here's the code that I used to solve the problem in case anyone is curious:

```
function is(obj, type) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1) == type;
}

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
var a=this;
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
};

Object.prototype.merge = function(b) {
  var a=this;
  for(var prop in b){
    if(is(b[prop],'Array')&&is(a[prop],'Array')){
      a[prop]=a[prop].concat(b[prop]).unique().sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(a)-parseInt(b)});
    }else{
      a[prop]=b[prop];
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

d[0].merge(d[1]) gives me exactly what I asked for.

Comment: are you asking for someone to write the function for you? Because I am sure you could pay someone to do that, at least try to do it first and then we can help you if you get stuck.

Comment: Did you work out the sort part? In your example the items are sorted as though they are numbers but they are actually strings. A default sort of the array would give you: `["0", "25", "44", "5"]`

Comment: I did use parseInt on purpose for my own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize the array merge you could sort it first and then check unique. The following would work if your objects only contain primitive values or arrays and an array only contain primitives of the same time:

```
var tools = {
  merge:function(a,b){
    var ret = {},key,i=-1,len=arguments.length;
    //as in your example, if both items have a property
    // named "en" then the property of the second one is used
    while(i++<len){
      this._merge(ret,arguments[i]);
    }
    for(key in ret){
      if(this._couldBeArray(ret[key])){
         //sort and plice are mutator functions that means 
         //they will change the object when called.
         this._unique(ret[key].sort(this._sortNum));
      }
    };
    return ret;
  },
  _couldBeArray:function(obj){
    return(typeof obj==="object" &&
      /Array\]$/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)));
  },
  _merge:function(a,b){
    var key;
    for(key in b){
      if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(this._couldBeArray(b[key])){
            //assuming it's an array, concat only does a 
            //  shallow copy as well though
            a[key]=(a[key])?b[key].concat(a[key]):
              (new b[key].constructor()).concat(b[key]);
        }else{
         a[key]=b[key];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  _unique:function(arr){
    var i=arr.length;
    while(i!==0){
      //unique assumes your array contains only primitives
      //  of same type for example: 0 does not equal "0"
      if(arr[i]===arr[i-1]){
        arr.splice(i,1);
      }
      i--;
    }
    if(arr[i]===arr[i+1])
      arr.splice(i,1);
  },
  _sortNum:function(a,b){
    return parseInt(a,10)-parseInt(b,10);
  }
};

var d=[
  {
    'fn':'john',
    'en':'doe',
    'k':['0','5','44']
  },
  {
    'en':'bark',
    'k':['25','44']
  },
  {
    'another':'another',
    'k':['100','44','45'],
    'primitiveArray':[1,2,3]
  },
  {
    'city':'NY',
    'primitiveArray':[2,3,4,5]
  }
];
console.log(tools.merge.apply(tools,d));
```

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery's `.extend`:

```
//$.extend(deepCopy,target,object1,object2);
var data = $.extend(true,{},d[0],d[1]);
console.log(data.en);
```

You can separately merge your inner arrays like this:

```
data.k=d[0].k.concat(d[1].k).unique();
console.log(data.k.join(","));
```

where `unique()` is a custom function added to Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = this.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};
```